# Which commonly used MIME types are plain text type?

Tags: http, mime-types, mime

As far as I know:

- types that begin with `text/`
- `application/json`
- `application/javascript`

Is there any other commonly used type?

Comment: Any reason you need this list? Maybe then we can help better?

Comment: I need to determine whether I need to use charset to decode the http response. If it responses an binary file, I won't decode it.

Comment: Your app will probably not be able to accept ALL request formats but only a subset like JSON,XML or Plaintext. So why not just react to those?

Comment: I just want to do as much as I can, though it is impossible to handle them all.

Comment: Is it some kind of file upload where you just want to store the file with correct encoding OR do you actually parse the contents of the file and execute some functions based on parsed info?

Comment: Yes, most times I need to parse the content, and take advantage of it.

Comment: You still are to vague I fear. You probably have a couple of parsers for very specific formats, focus on those. There is no parse-it-all, so why would you need a convert-it-all function.

Comment: For example, I am developing a web proxy, I want to append a inline <script> tag to every html page. I don't want to append content to image or any other binary files that will sent to browser. And parse each file is inefficient. Detect the http header may be a good solution.

Comment: I think thins is a very unreliable approach and will likely not work at all. You might have to rethink the project in general...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you won't be able to determine this from the MIME type. Also included in the plain text are all the language source codes, several data types, etc.

Wouldn't it be more logical to use the page encoding information, like:

`<`meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;**charset=ISO-8859-8**"`>`

If there is no charset in the header, you shouldn't decode it (though admittedly too many sites are not including the necessary information).